# Pivoting a data frame and pasting characters

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have two dataframes df and df_class

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(1,2,2,0),
                       b = c(2,1,2,2)),row.names=c(NA,-4L) ,class = "data.frame")
```

> ```
>   a b
> 1 1 2
> 2 2 1
> 3 2 2
> 4 0 2
> ```

```
df_class <- structure(list(atype = c("A1","A2","A3","A4"),
                                 btype = c("B1","B2","B3","B4")),row.names=c(NA,-4L) ,class = "data.frame")
```

> ```
>   atype btype
> 1    A1    B1
> 2    A2    B2
> 3    A3    B3
> 4    A4    B4
> ```

I changed df into a wide format using this (credit to Ronak Shah):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -row) %>%
  filter(value != 0) %>%
  group_by(row, value) %>%
  summarise(val = paste(name, collapse = "/")) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = val)
```

> ```
>   row    1   2
> 1   1    a   b
> 2   2    b   a
> 3   3 <NA> a/b
> 4   4 <NA>   b
> ```

Using the schema from df, I would like to obtain a transformed df_class like this:

> ```
>   1_type 2_type
> 1    A1    B1
> 2    B2    A2
> 3    NA    A3/B3
> 4    NA    B4
> ```

I tried combining df and df_class, then pivot_wider(cols=c("a","b")) but couldn't properly get the right 1_type, 2_type columns. In reality, I have 4 columns and am turning those into 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, we can create a column from 'df_class' after pivoting it to 'long' format by a join and then instead of the 'value' column `summarise`d use the column from the 'df_class'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -row) %>%
  left_join( df_class %>% 
                mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
                pivot_longer(cols = -row) %>%
                mutate(name = str_remove(name, 'type')),
     by = c('row', 'name')) %>% 
  filter(value.x != 0) %>%
  group_by(row, value.x = str_c(value.x, "_type")) %>%
  summarise(val = str_c(value.y, collapse="/")) %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = value.x, values_from = val) %>%
  select(-row)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  `1_type` `2_type`
#  <chr>    <chr>   
#1 A1       B1      
#2 B2       A2      
#3 <NA>     A3/B3   
#4 <NA>     B4
```

---

Or another option is to bind the datasets together with `bind_cols` and make use of `names_sep` while doing `pivot_longer`

```
df %>%
   rename_all(~ str_c(., '_number')) %>%
   bind_cols(df_class %>%
                rename_all(~ str_replace(., 'type', '_type'))) %>% 
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -rn, names_sep = "_", names_to = c("group", ".value")) %>%
   filter(number != 0) %>% 
   group_by(rn, number = str_c(number, "_type")) %>%
   summarise(type = str_c(type, collapse="/")) %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = number, values_from = type) %>% 
   select(-rn)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  `1_type` `2_type`
#  <chr>    <chr>   
#1 A1       B1      
#2 B2       A2      
#3 <NA>     A3/B3   
#4 <NA>     B4
```